# javascript validation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my form validation function:

```
function validateForm() {
    valid = true;
    var a=document.forms["checkout"]["fname"].value;
    if (a==null || a=="")
    {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }
    var b=document.forms["checkout"]["lname"].value;
    if (b==null || b=="")
    {
    alert("Last name must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }
    var c=document.forms["checkout"]["address"].value;
    if (c==null || c=="")
    {
    alert("Address must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }   
    var d=document.forms["checkout"]["email"].value;
    if (d==null || d=="")
    {
    alert("Email address must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }
    var e=document.forms["checkout"]["email"].value;
    if(!validateEmail(e)){
    alert("Must be a valid email address");
    valid = false;
    }   
    var f=document.forms["checkout"]["phone"].value;
    if (f==null || f=="")
    {
    alert("Phone number must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }
    var g=document.forms["checkout"]["phone"].value;
    if(!validatePhone(g)){
    alert("Must be a valid phone number");
    valid = false;
    }   
    var h=document.forms["checkout"]["card"].value;
    if (h==null || h=="")
    {
    alert("Credit card info must be filled out");
    valid = false;
    }
    var i=document.forms["checkout"]["card"].value;
    if(!validateCard(i)){
    alert("Must be a valid credit card number");
    valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
 function validateEmail(email) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.)    {2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return pattern.test(email);
}
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var ppattern = new RegExp(/^[\d ]+$/);
    return ppattern.test(phone);
}
function validateCard(card) {
    var cpattern = new RegExp(/(?:\d[ ]?){12,17}\d/);
    return cpattern.test(card);
}
```

The form validates correctly until it reaches the email address. No matter what I put it says the email is invalid. Also for some reason it is cycling through all the alert messages when it used to only check one at a time.

Edited to add the php validations:

```
if(isset($_POST['SubmitForm'])){
if(empty($_POST['fname'])){
    echo "First name cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if(empty($_POST['lname'])){
    echo "Last name cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if(empty($_POST['address'])){
    echo "Address field cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if(empty($_POST['email'])){
    echo "Email field cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if($_POST['email']){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 
    $match = preg_match($regex,$email);
    if(!$match)
    echo "Not a valid email address!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if(empty($_POST['phone'])){
    echo "Phone number cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if($_POST['phone']){
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $reg = '/^[\(]?(\d{0,3})[\)]?[\s]?[\-]?(\d{3})[\s]?[\-]?(\d{4})[\s]?[x]?(\d*)$/';
    $pmatch = preg_match($reg, $phone);
    if (!$pmatch)
    echo "Not a valid phone number!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if(empty($_POST['card'])){
    echo "Card field cannot be empty!<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if($_POST['card']){
    $card = $_POST['card'];
    $match = preg_match("#[0-9]#",$card);
    if(strlen($card) < '13')
    echo "Card field must be at least 13 digits <br/><br/>";
    return false;
    if(!$match)
    echo "Card number must be numeric<br/><br/>";
    return false;
}
if($_POST['month']){
$month = $_POST['month'];
if($month < 05)
    echo "Expired credit card";
    return false;
}
return true;
$fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $phone = $_SESSION['phone'];
    $representation = json_encode($_SESSION['cart'],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $pfile = fopen("orders.txt","a+");
    rewind($pfile);
    fwrite($pfile, "\r\n$fname:$lname:$email:$phone:$representation");
    fclose($pfile);
}
```

Comment: `[\w-\s]` looks pretty suspicious to me.

Comment: Ok now when it finishes checking it loads a blank page instead of doing the php checks...why is this?

Comment: Using new RegExp with an actual regexp is also suspicious to me... Other than that we can't tell you what is wrong with your code if you don't show us the concerned part, can you please show us your php ?

Comment: @aduch sorry just added it now.